# Script to create or drop all primary keys in Netezza

Tags: sql, metadata, netezza, information-schema

I am trying to create a script that will drop and create all the primary keys in my Netezza database. Something similar to this article for SQL Server: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2321.script-to-create-or-drop-all-primary-keys.aspx

What's the best way to go about that? I found another solution that uses cross apply, but like cursor, that's not supported in Netezza. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have two databases with the same tables.  Netezza has keys, SQL Server does not.  I need to apply the primary keys to the SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
--DROP CONSTRAINTS
SELECT DISTINCT ' ALTER TABLE '||RTRIM(SCHEMA)||'.'||RELATION|| ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' 
|| constraintname || ' CASCADE;' from _V_RELATION_KEYDATA    
--optional: WHERE DATABASE=<DATABASE> 
--OR WHERE SCHEMA='<SCHEMANAME>;

--ADD PK CONSTRAINTS 
SELECT DISTINCT ' ALTER TABLE '||RTRIM(SCHEMA)||'.'||RELATION|| ' ADD CONSTRAINT '
|| constraintname || ' PRIMARY KEY('|| trim(trailing ',' from replace(replace
(XMLSerialize(XMLagg(XMLElement('X',attname)))
,'<X>','')
,'</X>',','))  ||' ) INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;' 
from _V_RELATION_KEYDATA    
GROUP BY SCHEMA,CONSTRAINTNAME, RELATION;
--optional: WHERE DATABASE=<DATABASE> 
--OR WHERE SCHEMA='<SCHEMANAME>;
```

Make sure to run the --ADD PK Constraints and save the DDL output before dropping the constraints